# Conflict with scroll indicator and full page scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to implement a scroll indicator on the page, but for some reason when adding automatic scrolling by section using CSS, it breaks and fills only on the footer, I don't know how to fix this and what is the error here?

Maybe it makes sense to try to fill the scroll indicator specifically on section blocks?

globals.css :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

page.tsx :

```
import ...

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ScrollIndicator />
      <div className="section"> <Dome /> </div>
      <div className="section"> <About /> </div>
      <div className="section"> <Lodge /> </div>
      <div className="section"> <AboutAdd /> </div>
      <div className="section"> <Reviews /> </div>
      <div className="section"> <Blog /> </div>
      <div className="section"> <Contacts /> </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

layout.tsx :

```
import './globals.css';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';

import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import { Footer } from './components/Footer';

...

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={font.className}>
        <Navbar />
        <main> {children} </main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html> 
  );
};
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/navbar-hotel-sandbox-63l7v7?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0007356hvvc3hsr5%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0002356hhb9qjtb3%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0004356h3wx5fwe7%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0006356huat6uabw%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B44.41530421441243%252C55.58469578558757%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq5jcbjq0002356hhb9qjtb3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0002356hhb9qjtb3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clq5jcbjq0006356huat6uabw%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0006356huat6uabw%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0005356h40rmdrt7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0005356h40rmdrt7%2522%257D%252C%2522clq5jcbjq0004356h3wx5fwe7%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0003356h2wuh7gug%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0004356h3wx5fwe7%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5jcbjq0003356h2wuh7gug%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)